# SQL Server - Identify Hex Range in Varchar

Tags: sql-server, hex

I have a table with a varchar field.  It contains a number of characters causing us issues, and I believe they fall between hex range 0x80 and 0x9F (I believe they are the 32 characters in the cp1252 character set that have different mappings from ISO-8859-1).  I'm trying to identify them using the below query, but it's not working (returning basically every value with a patindex of 1).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
select top 2000
A.*, 
patindex('%[\x80-\x9F]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, MyField) AS PatIndexPosition
from MyTable A
where patindex('%[\x80-\x9F]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, MyField) > 0
```

Comment: I don't think these escape sequences work in SQL Server. Try `concat('%[', char(128), '-', char(159), ']%')` instead of `'%[\x80-\x9F]%'`. (Replace `char()` by `nchar()` if the type of `myfield` is an N-string type.

Comment: This one is showing promise, thank you!  I will look into it in more detail next week.